# Highlight all occurrences of word in avalonedit

Tags: avalonedit

I want to highlight all the occurrences of the selected word when the mouse is double clicked. This question [Highlight all occurrences of selected word in AvalonEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223674/highlight-all-occurrences-of-selected-word-in-avalonedit) does answer how to do it with a Document Colorizer, but I am not sure how to pass the word in. Also, how do i trigger the recoloring with the mouse double click ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to highlight the words simply by changing the background color, there's one simple solution: Use an `IBackgroundRenderer`

To store the parts of the document that should be highlighted you can use a `TextSegmentCollection<T>`. This collection stores `TextSegment` instances, which you can then use in the `IBackgroundRenderer.Draw` method implementation.

The `Layer` property should return the layer on which the `IBackgroundRenderer` renders. This can simply be `KnownLayer.Selection` to render behind the selection.

The `Draw` method can be implemented as follows:

```cs
if (!textView.VisualLinesValid)
    return;

var visualLines = textView.VisualLines;
if (visualLines.Count == 0)
    return;

int viewStart = visualLines.First().FirstDocumentLine.Offset;
int viewEnd = visualLines.Last().LastDocumentLine.EndOffset;

foreach (TextSegment result in currentResults.FindOverlappingSegments(viewStart, viewEnd - viewStart)) 
    BackgroundGeometryBuilder geoBuilder = new BackgroundGeometryBuilder();
    geoBuilder.AlignToMiddleOfPixels = true;
    geoBuilder.CornerRadius = 3;
    geoBuilder.AddSegment(textView, result);
    Geometry geometry = geoBuilder.CreateGeometry();
    if (geometry != null) {
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(markerBrush, markerPen, geometry);
    }
}
```

A short explanation: First you have to check whether the `VisualLines` are valid and if there are any. If there aren't, there's nothing to do, thus we exit.

Then you can calculate the visible range by using the start offset of the first visible document line and the end offset of the last visible document line. This should speed up the rendering process, because we only process what's currently visible.

`FindOverlappingSegments` returns a list of all segments that overlap with the given range.

Then we use the `BackgroundGeometryBuilder`, a helper class, to create a nice-looking geometry for the highlight. This is also used for the currently selected text in AvalonEdit.

To add it to the `TextEditor` use: `textEditor.TextArea.TextView.BackgroundRenderers.Add(renderer);`

If you expose the results as property you can then use: `renderer.Results.Add(result);`

To refresh the screen you can use `textEditor.TextArea.TextView.InvalidateLayer(KnownLayer.Selection);` if it is not done automatically.

Comment: I am trying my best to implement this without any external help but getting nowhere. I am very new to C# but I need a way to highlight all occurrences of a word in AvalonEdit like OP. 

I've gotten this far: https://pastebin.com/MGeHrCf0.

How do I update `currentResults` from outside the `HighlightSelectedWordBackgroundRenderer` to include all of my word occurrences?

I just don't get how the matches get populated since `TextSegmentCollection` only has a getter. 

Sorry if I'm missing something stupid. Like I said, I am very new to C#. Any guidance would be really appreciated.